# How to make Webpack-dev-server work with react-router inside Vagrant?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vagrant, webpack-dev-server, react-router-dom

I am working on a React / Typescript project using Webpack (v.4.44.2), along with Vagrant. For routing purposes, I tried to implement a BrowserHistory from `react-router-dom`. As you can imagine, `http://localhost:8000/myUrl` didn't work properly on refresh / manual entry at this point. After a bit of research, I tried without success to setup `devServer.historyApiFallback` and `output.publicPath`, but nothing works.

My webpack setup looks like this :

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'] // `.js` for external libs (/node_modules/)
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/i, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/i, use: 'prettier-loader', enforce: 'pre', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css?$/i, use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html') }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'main.css' })
  ],
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      // index: '/',
    },
    // historyApiFallback: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    public: '10.10.10.61',
    port: 8000,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see, I tried several values for `historyApiFallback`, but I feel like I'm missing something, as I still have the 404 error on refresh. As I'm inside a Vagrant, I wonder if it's an issue regarding the fact that dev bundles are not written to the disk ? or maybe something related to the Vagrant network setup ?

My Vagrantfile is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # see https://webpack.js.org/guides/development-vagrant/
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.10.10.61"

  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.define "dev", primary: true do |app|
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "someImage"

      d.name = "#{PROJECT}_dev"

      d.has_ssh = true
      d.ports = ["0.0.0.0:8000:8000"]
      d.env = DOCKER_ENV
    end
    [...]
  end
end
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved as follow

Vagrant setup :

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'] // `.js` for external libs (/node_modules/)
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/i, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/i, use: 'prettier-loader', enforce: 'pre', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css?$/i, use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html')
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'main.css' })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true, // this was what messed me up : in my URL, I have IDs, which for some reason contains dots
      index: '/', // same as output.publicPath
    },
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    public: '10.10.10.61',
    port: 8000,
    watchContentBase: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  }
};
```

No tricky stuff related to the filesystem or vagrant. Just an URL "dot" issue that I didn't notice -__-"